# md5deep create checksum for directory with relative paths

Tags: checksums

How do I create checksum for a directory with `md5deep`, for checking duplication in another location?

For example:

I want to create checksum file for `/home/user/Documents` and I want check duplicate in `/media/usb/Documents`. If I use this:

```
md5deep -r -s /home/user/Documents > checksum.md5
```

The checksum file has the absolute path of the directory like:

```
f110abe5b3cfd324c2e5128eb4733879  /home/user/Documents/Dir01/file01
```

How do I make a path like `Dir01/file01`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `-l` option. From [`man md5deep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/md5deep):

```
-l     Enables relative file paths. Instead of  printing  the  absolute
       path for each file, displays the relative file path as indicated
       on the command line. This flag may not be  used  in  conjunction
       with the -b flag.
```

So do:

```
cd /home/user/
md5deep -lrs Documents > checksum.md5
```

For example,

```
$ md5deep -lrs Downloads | head -1
699cd26d7fe0bada29eb1b2cd7b50e4b  Downloads/Sublime Text 2.0.2 x64.tar.bz2
```

Comment: thx for respond but this message i got "md5sum: invalid option -- 'l'
Try 'md5sum --help' for more information."

Comment: ahh ic ic, not md5sum but md5deep thx @muru

Comment: @Ivan sorry, that was typo